# mysqli_query not accepting my mysqli_connect and proper use of parameters of mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

i have set my configdb.php on a different page and include it on my other php pages..

here is my configdb.php

```
<?php
$hostname ="localhost";
$username ="root";
$password ="";
$db ="practicedb";
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect to server");
mysqli_select_db($connect,$db) or die("database not found!");
?>
```

these are the errors that i get:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: configdb in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/practicesystem/add.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/practicesystem/add.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/practicesystem/add.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: configdb in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/practicesystem/add.php on line 28
```

this is my add.php where i INSERT items into database from the $_POST method from a previous php page..

```
<?php
include "configdb.php";



$studid=$_POST['studid'];
$lastname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$firstname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$middlename= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['middlename']);
$email=$_POST['email'];


$check = "SELECT * from studinfo where stud_id = '".$studid."'";
$qry = mysqli_query($configdb,$check);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($qry); 


if($num_rows > 0){
// Here we are checking if username is already exist or not.

    echo "The person you have entered is already existing. Please try again.";
    echo '<a href="index.php">Try Again</a>';
    exit;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO studinfo (stud_id,lastname,firstname,middlename,email) VALUES ('".$studid."','".$lastname."','".$firstname."','".$middlename."','".$email."');";
//echo $query;
mysqli_query($configdb, $query);
echo "Thank You for Registration.";
echo '<a href="index.php">Click Here</a> to login you account.';
exit;
?>
```

i don't know and i am not sure what to put on the first parameter of mysqli_query..
i tried putting this code `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicedb");` it worked but its not practical putting that on every php page where i should connect to the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another question on a silly typo...

**$connect** = mysqli_connect( ...
vs.
$qry = mysqli_query(**$configdb**,$check);

so the error message clearly says: **Undefined variable: configdb**

Comment: i see, so i'm gonna use the $connect from the $configdb page right? thanks! i thought the first parameter was the page itself.. silly me... lemme try that!

Comment: omg, that worked.. thank you very much for that... i was rather giggling when i read your name.. i really need that haha! thanks again!